# Calculate Intersections only when Objects Moved or Calculate constantly

Tags: performance, game-engine, intersection

My Question is a bit abstract, to make it clearer i try to explain it.

Lets say i have 5 Objects that are not moveable and have static positions.
My Main Object, that is not static and moves around intersects with one of those Objects, then i want to know that and show an response to that. So my conclusion was to iterate through all of those Objects and calculate the intersections with them. But what if i dont have 5 of those  Objects. Lets say i have 100 of them. Is it then faster to bind an boolean to the Main Object that is true when the Object moves and when not otherwise. And only calculate intersections when that Boolean is true ?

An other Option i was thinking of was to constantly calculate the distance between all Objects and when the distance is shorter then before test for intersections. So if an Object moves away i only calculate distance but if it comes near i have to calculate the distance **and** the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I layer my objects so Static (non moving) and dynamic (moving) are processed differently.

It truly depends on what your trying to do honestly, but the optimal way to handle this is to build BSP of all collide able geometry and use that for processing collision rather than doing a linear search through all objects.

Your going to save processing time on the frames the main object doesn't move by using your boolean method, but honestly it isn't a permanent solution.

Comment: +1 for the mention of BSP trees. That's the key to making the system scalable.